# Mock SOAP request and response

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot

For mocking currently we are recording SOAP request and response on file system with specific folder structure such as 
Request folder

- test1_request.xml
- test2_request.xml
- test3_request.xml

Response folder

- test1_response.xml
- test2_response.xml
- test2_response.xml

When we run our test suite first we scan through these directory and store file content in a hashmap e.g.
Map.put(request, response)

Once all file contents are stored in map we start executing our test cases. In this process we construct the soap Request and pass it to our controller which in turn call this map and find a corresponding response for the request.

Now problem is over a period of time we have accumulated thousands of test cases and req/res which is slowing down the overall test execution process. For your information we have integrated this into our build process so everytime build is triggered we execute all our unit tests.

Any design recommendation to improve it?

I was thinking index these req/res files using solr or lucene but not sure if they provide any map machenism where in I pass soap request and get the matching response.

Answer (score 0):

In case an incoming request must be completly equal to the cached request you can create a hash for the cached request and name the response files accordingly.

In your controller you can then create a hash for the request and you will directly find the response just opening the correct file.

Alternativly you can create a csv/properties file with "request hash" to "response filename" and just load this file. Should be much faster then always loading all requests and responses. This is more or less a simple index, lucene/solr should be really too much for just this use-case.